# Add Parentheses in First Element of First Line

Tags: awk, command

I would like to add parentheses around "8" - the first element in the first line. An example of my file follows.

```
8   089.3   96.72   61  2   0   4240    4300    2420    2360    3e-20    102
8   089.3   96.67   60  0   1   4239    4296    2419    2360    1e-18   96.9
```

I used the following command to achieve the result.

```
awk '{print "("$0")"}' file.txt1
```

The result follows.

```
(8  089.3   96.72   61  2   0   4240    4300    2420    2360    3e-20    102)
(8  089.3   96.67   60  0   1   4239    4296    2419    2360    1e-18   96.9)
```

And I want output such as the following.

```
(8) 089.3   96.72   61  2   0   4240    4300    2420    2360    3e-20    102
(8) 089.3   96.67   60  0   1   4239    4296    2419    2360    1e-18   96.9
```

Comment: $0 is the whole record = whole line. use $1

Comment: Is the file tab separated, or are the fields separated by one or more spaces.

Comment: the file is separeted by one tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the field separators in the original file are tabs (and/or you want the output to be tab-delimited), then you may use `awk` like so:

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '{ $1 = sprintf("(%s)", $1) } 1' file
```

This modifies the first field and then outputs the re-formed line with the modified field.  The `1` at the end causes the output and may be replaced by `{ print }`.

Your code is doing something similar to this, but you use `$0`, which is the contents of the *whole* line, not just the first field.

You may also use `sed`, which would leave the rest of the line untouched:

```
sed -E 's/^([^[:blank:]]+)/(\1)/' file
```

This matches any non-blank string of characters at the very start of the line, and replaces these with the same string of characters in parentheses.

Another variation with `sed` that first inserts a `(` at the start of the line and then inserts a `)` before the first blank character (a "blank" character means a space or a tab):

```
sed -E -e 's/^/(/' -e 's/([[:blank:]])/)\1/' file
```

The `awk` solution is more flexible, as it allows you to easily modify *any* field on the line, but the `sed` solutions allows you to keep the delimiters that you have in the original file, whether they be multiple spaces or tabs.  I only included the `sed` solutions here because you wanted to modify the first field on the line, and that field is readily available to (easy to find with) a `sed` program.

Comment: Thank you at you and everyone for your help, but especially for your time, I used: awk -v OFS='\t' '{ $1 = sprintf("(%s)", $1) } 1' file, and It works :).

Comment: This will convert several spaces (runs of tabs and spaces) to one single tab.

Comment: @isaac I know, and I believe I mentioned this in the answer.

Comment: No, you did not. All you said is: *you want the output to be tab-delimited* but never mentined the fact that two, three or more tabs and spaces will be converted to **one** output tab.

Comment: @isaac There, I've fixed it.

Comment: And now you fail to note that: 1.- a leading tab will lead to an empty first 
 field `()`. 2.- That any repeated tab will change the field numbering and 3.- That any spaces will be included as part of the field `(  8  )`.  ;-)

Comment: @isaac 1) That's expected. A leading tab indicates an empty first field. 2) No, the first field will always be the field before the first tab. 3) Yes, because spaces are ordinary characters too, not field delimiters.

Comment: @Kusalananda To your comment I must add that your first solution (now edited) used a default FS of one space. In that case it will fail in all three points: 1.- False: A leading tab will **not** be used as a delimiter, the first field will not be empty. 2.- Any run of tabs and spaces will be used as one delimiter, but **not** if the FS is changed to one tab. That will affect the field numbering. 3.- No. Spaces are delimiters with your first answer, now that you changed the answer to a tab, the spaces do lose the special condition of being used as delimiters. That is a change. Those are facts.

Comment: @Kusalananda Those are the facts. You may choose to make (or not make) a note in your answer. Are your comments extending the discussion to just generate some noise?.

Comment: @isaac I'm sorry, Isaac, I thought your previous comment was about the solution after my fix, but you are correct on all accounts about my initial solution. If you want me to update the solution further, I'm welcoming constructive suggestions.